# why I can't post to laravel rout using jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, html, laravel, file-upload

I'm trying to submit a single value as following?

**HTML:**

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data" name="frmanalyse" id="frmanalyse">
{{ csrf_field() }}
 <label for="marginsource" style="float: left;  width:150px; text-align:left;">Margin Source</label>
 <input type="file" name="marginsource" id="marginsource" >
 <br />
 </form>
```

**script:**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $( "#frmanalyse" ).submit(function(event) {
            $.post( "marginanalyser", {username: "medo ampir"}, function( data ) {
                alert(data);
            });
            event.preventDefault();
  });
```

**in laravel routes:**

```
Route::post('marginanalyser',function(Request $request){
 echo $request->input('username');

 $file = $request->file('marginsource');
echo 'File Name: '.$file->getClientOriginalName();
});
```

nothing shows in the message at all.

Comment: Could you press f12 in your browser and click the tab network, after that submit your form, and check the post request that is being created, what does the page contain? An error?

Comment: nothing at all.

Comment: But there is an alert? Because the alert should only show when the post request is made...

Comment: it doesn't show, that means that the request wasn't submitted or the response is not made.

Comment: F12, console tab, shows an error. "TypeError: 'append' called on an object that does not implement interface FormData."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your JavaScript to use FormData as you aren't submitting the file

```
$( "#frmanalyse" ).submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('marginsource', $('#marginsource')[0].files[0]);
    formData.append('username', "medo ampir");

    $.ajax({
        url : window.location.origin + "/marginanalyser",
        type: "POST",
        data : formData,
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            //if fails     
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: still nothing, and when I try to remove "event.preventDefault();" the post opens a blank page .( the marginanalyser post route) but empty

Comment: When you remove `event.preventDefault` it doesn't use ajax to submit the form and backs to default form submission, hence displays blank page

Comment: so back to the main issue, why the data wasn't submited?

Comment: nothing happens, but the console logged " [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 165ms]"

Comment: When you click on the error, whats the detail that's shown next to it?

Comment: it goes to network tab and there is a header and response, but from the review it seems that it is a token mismatch issue, i'm not sure why it is not sent in the form data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139903/discussion-between-linktoahref-and-medo-ampir).

Comment: Still can't figure it out. I appreciate if you could help.

Comment: @medoampir Please check the updated code. I had initialised the formdata variable outside the scope of form submit hence it returned as null. I tested the above code and now you would be able to get file data